# Vall-e pytorch torch.load returns dict

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I am using `enhuiz/vall-e` but running into a error which is
`File "vall-e/vall_e/main.py", line 30, in main ar = torch.load(args.ar_ckpt).to(args.device) AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'to'`

The issue is mentioned but no one has solved it `https://github.com/enhuiz/vall-e/issues/64`

I am using this google colab to reproduce it (NOTE: i added `!pip install deepspeed==0.8.3`)
`https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wEze0kQ0gt9B3bQmmbtbSXCoCTpq5vg-?usp=sharing`

Answer (score 1):

The pytorch load and save methods can work with tensors as well as dictionaries of tensors. So `ar_ckpt` argument was saved as a dictionary.
You need to check the file itself and find out the key for the state_dict, for example try printing `torch.load(args.ar_ckpt).keys()` and let's say, you found the key for the state_dict tensor is called "state", then you should modify the code to `torch.load(args.ar_ckpt)["state"].to(args.device)`.

If you don't want to change the original code, you can change the file itself in an outside environment.
read the state file and then save it without the dict:

```py
state = torch.load(args.ar_ckpt)["state"]
torch.save(state, args.ar_ckpt)  # or you can save it in a different name
```

Comment: This is a good start but the problem is that all of the `.keys()` do not have to function `.to(args.ar_ckpt)` I am thinking it maybe a error in the ar_ckpt file but will update when a solution is found.